# Deploy files in the localState folder during installation of a store app

Tags: deployment, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, winjs

I am building an app for windows store and I need some default and example data to be in the localstate folder (`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder`) when the app run the first time.

The folder and files structure is a bit complex and I tryed to copy the files at the start of the application, but I can't manage that way.

Is it possible to have files being copied automatically from the installation folder to the localstate folder during the store app installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, customization of the app install process isn't currently supported. You have to do this as part of your first run processing.

One possibility is that you include the data in your package as a .ZIP or other compressed file and use an appropriate library to expand that file into a folder structure on startup. That could simplify your logic considerably. (I don't have a library to recommend; it's just an idea.)

Comment: I thought about it but then to unzip the folder I would have to go thrue the full process of recursively read the whole folder structure and extract one file at a time. I couldn't find any library that does it automatically. But it is good to know that customization is not supported. Thanks

Comment: The best approach, then, might be to have the structure you want in your package's hierarchy, and then do a deep copy of those files to local appdata. Tedious code, for sure. Too bad StorageFolder doesn't have a copy method.